# how to combine server code with sql query in aspx

Tags: asp.net

I don't know how to insert the call to GetConstraints -which ets the where ...
The code below gives an error at `<%=selec...`

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="OrdersSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"


  <%="SelectCommand=\"SELECT Id , IsResolved, Feedback, IsCanceled, RatingFromUser, SubmitionTime, IsPendingResponse, IsReceived, AllowAutomaticDIspatching FROM OrderSet"+GetConstraints() %>+"\"" >
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Maybe should insert space after OrderSet :)